# Redirecting to included URLS from RedirectView

Tags: django

Say I have a URL setup like this in my Django 1.6 project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^some-path/', include('someapp.urls')),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='some-path/', permanent=False)),
)
```

…but I want to change "some-path" to "changed-path" instead, and in the process realize that I've got it hardcoded in an extra place: the `RedirectView` setup!

Is there a proper way to do something like this, reversing to an included bundle of URLs?

```
# NOT WORKING! Django ignores `name=` when using `include()`
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^changed-path/', include('someapp.urls'), name='foo'),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='foo', permanent=False)),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to go to your `urls.py` file from someapp and get the name of your base url.
Let's assume it's something like:

```
# someapp/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'someapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'your view', name='foo'),
    ...
)
```

And now in your main urls file, you can write everything like this:

```
# WORKING! Because Django likes namespaces 
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^changed-path/', include('someapp.urls', namespace='bar')),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='bar:foo', permanent=False)),
)
```

Comment: Thanks; I especially appreciate the namespace example. Unfortunately, this is also what I was afraid of — seems like a bad choice between either repeating myself (as in my question) or having to tie the parent logic to internal details of a child (as in your answer). I think your latter way is probably better since whenever I'm building URLs I'm gonna need to know the names across apps anyway.